# What is the meaning of magnitude of the noise power spectral density?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density

Say we have a noise power spectral density that has the following form (I think the question is the same for more general forms as well)
$$
S(f) = Af^\alpha,
$$
In experiments people usually discuss the magnitude of the noise at $1\,\text{Hz}$ and give a number for that, for example
$$
S(1\,\text{Hz}) = C \,\, \frac{u^2}{\text{Hz}}
$$
where $C$ is a constant number, and $u$ is the unit for the underlying measured noisy quantity (e.g., Volts or flux quantum).

**Questions**

1. What is the intuition for understanding the meaning of magnitude of the noise power spectral density at  $1\,\text{Hz}$? How that relates to the deviations of the underlying stochastic process?
2. What if we look at the magnitude of the noise power spectral density at say  $1\,\text{kHz}$? What does that mean?

Comment: hm I've never seen anyone discuss the noise PSD at 1 Hz. That seems to be a very specific special case, and it's only special for your specific $S(f)$, so your question really doesn't generalize to other forms!

Comment: So, when you set $f=1$ in your $S(f)$, what do you get? This really seems like a basic exercise in "how to use a formula".

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, you are given a constant number with appropriate units, which should work for any form of $S(f)$.

Comment: yes, but your claim is "I think the question is the same for more general forms as well" and that's what I don't agree to. Again, have you inserted $f=1$ (no units) in your $S(f)=Af^\alpha$ and realized what you get?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the point, a bit here:

In your formula

$$S(f)=Af^\alpha,$$

you forgot to actually state "what" $\alpha$ and $f$ are supposed to be, but from the formula itself it's quite clear that they *have* to be real numbers: if either $f$ or $\alpha$ "contained" any units, then the result of $Af^\alpha$ would have different physical units (not magnitude, units!) for different $f$. That makes physically no sense.

So, what you can insert as $f$ in your formula can never be $1\,\text{Hz}$; it must be a real number, not a real number times a unit!

Therefore, the question

> What is the intuition for understanding the meaning of magnitude of the noise power spectral density at 1Hz?

is a bit off. $f=1$ is what you mean, and quite elementary,

$$S(f=1) = A1^\alpha = A,$$

so that's the whole significance (I hoped to point that out in my comment and it seems I failed); you get $A$, with all its physical units.

> What if we look at the magnitude of the noise power spectral density at say 1kHz? What does that mean?

So, we cannot insert 1 kHz into $S(f)$, but keeping the consistency to above, 1 kHz corresponds to $f=1000$.

So, that has no "special" meaning (like any other $f$). It just gives us the value of the power spectral density at that frequency. So, "what does that mean" is: it's what the PSD is at 1 kHz, nothing more, nothing less.